# Extending javafx.application.Application with superclass. Why is Override ignored in subclass?

Tags: javafx, overriding, extends

I need to define a *type* of apps from that I extend actual apps (e.g. in this `TestApp_sub` below). Sadly, these actual apps override methods do not work. It seems they are ignored completely. The following package should print

```
A
B
```

on execution. But only prints

```
A
```

instead.

---

### Code

Superclass based on javafx:

```
package overrideIssue;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApp_super extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {
            Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane(), 640, 480);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

            myMethod();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch();
        }

        public void myMethod(){
            System.out.println("A");
        }
}
```

The subclass (an actual app/ contains the ignored override):

```
package overrideIssue;

public class TestApp_sub extends TestApp_super {

    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        super.myMethod();
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
package overrideIssue;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        TestApp_sub.main( args );
    }
}
```

---

### Suggestions

According to [javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overriding-in-java) the following should be fulfilled:
Rules for Java Method Overriding

- The method must have the same name as in the parent class
- The method must have the same parameter as in the parent class.
- There must be an IS-A relationship (inheritance).

(However it's a `javafx.application.Application`,  which is not instantiated as an object.)
I found several seemingly similar questions on stackoverflow, but I can't see the solution on this one however. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [`Application#launch(String...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#launch(java.lang.String...)):

> Launch a standalone application. This method is typically called from the `main` method. It must not be called more than once or an exception will be thrown. **This is equivalent to `launch(TheClass.class, args)` where `TheClass` is the immediately enclosing class of the method that called `launch`** [emphasis added].

In your case, the "immediately enclosing class" of the method which called `launch` is `TestApp_super`. This means that it's `TestApp_super` which is instantiated and used as the application class, not the `TestApp_sub`. In other words, you're not using the class with the overridden method and the output you're seeing is expected.

To use the class you want there's at least three options:

1. Use [`Application#launch(Class,String...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#launch(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String...)):

   ```java
   package overrideIssue;

   import javafx.application.Application;

   public class App {
       public static void main( String[] args ) {
           Application.launch(TestApp_sub.class, args);
       }
   }
   ```

   Now you're explicitly telling JavaFX which class to use as the application class. You could even add logic to inspect the command line arguments and decide which class to pass to `launch`.
2. Simply use the application you want as the main class. In other words, specify the appropriate class on the command-line.
3. Add a `public static void main(String[])` method to the `TestApp_sub` class as well.

   ```java
   package overrideIssue;

   public class TestApp_sub extends TestApp_super {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           launch(args);
       }    

       @Override
       public void myMethod() {
           super.myMethod();
           System.out.println("B");
       }
   }
   ```

   This does not *override* the `main` method in the `TestApp_super` class, it only *hides* it—static methods cannot be overridden. Which static method is invoked is determined by which declared type the method was invoked on; notice I said *declared type*, not *runtime type*, as the static method to be invoked is decided at compile-time. Since you use `TestApp_sub.main(args)` the method in `TestApp_sub` is invoked (assuming you've added it like above). However, if you were to use `TestApp_super.main(args)` it would call the method in `TestApp_super` regardless of a method with the same signature being present in the subclass.

   Now that `TestApp_sub` is the "immediately enclosing class" of the method that called `launch` it will be `TestApp_sub` that's instantiated and used.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Option 1 + 3 work fine for me. Great to have several options. For Opt.3 I didn't know I could _hide_ the method this way, instead of override.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is the way `Application.launch` works. Goes through the call stack to determine the class that invoked `Application.launch` and constructs an instance of this class to use for launching the application. You haven't changed the fact that the `main` method calling `Application.launch` is part of the `TestApp_super` class.

Not the compiler determines the class containing the `main` method for `TestApp_sub.main( args );` at compile time, so there's no info left in the byte code about the fact that you were using `TestApp_sub`.

You can pass the application class to the overloaded version of `launch` though:

```
Application.launch(TestApp_sub.class, args);
```

Comment: This works!! Simple. Thanks a lot. I had no clue about the java compiler and actual byte code, interesting.